# Log highlighted lines to window in irssi

Tags: irc, irssi

I usually keep an irssi session running on my server at all times.

Often times it also takes me quite a while between remembering that I in fact have it running.

Therefore I'd like to know if there's an easy way to log all lines that are highlighted to a custom window, such that I later, when I return, can see what people have said that was directed at me.

Most useful would of course be if it logged both nickname, time and place (channel, network) of the message.

I've been looking around, and haven't managed to get anything working which accomplishes this, so it would be splendid if such a thing existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the hilightwin.pl script available at http://scripts.irssi.org/

Comment: I must have done something wrong last time I tried it; but I used http://quadpoint.org/articles/irssi#hilight_window to set it up this time and it works. Thanks!