# How do I highlight my own messages?

Tags: irssi

I would like to highlight the whole line of messages I write in a public channel.

Thought `/hilight -mask {mynick}!*@*` would make it work. I've tried a number of switches.

I wonder if the default behavior of just highlighting my nick (as opposed to the whole line) is overriding my hilight. I've tried altering the priority to no avail. Is there a place where I could edit this default behavior?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/228072/log-highlighted-lines-to-window-in-irssi?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

to use a specific color for all your lines in irssi, you can use the following:

```
/format own_msg {ownmsgnick $2 {ownnick $0}}%g$1
```

the last part `%g` is the color, here it's green.
so all my lines will be green.
don't forget to `/save` to make the setting permanent.

i know it's a bit late to reply to this, but i was searching for that info too
and maybe it can help others later on, who might want the same setting.